# Geocoding: call longitude latitude from mysql table

Tags: mysql, geocoding

I'm not very good at programming and just a beginner. My English is not that good, so I hope you can understand my question.

I'm interested to make a map like this but with a few modification: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

I have a mysql table with 3 columns: unit, lat, lng.
I want to make a map where user input the unit name, then it will look up for the value in mysql table, take the longitude latitude value, and display the address in google maps marker tooltips.

How do I do that? Thank you before!

Comment: FYI, Converting an address to a lat,long is called geocoding. Converting a lat,long into an adddress is called reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this you need to learn `webservices` then only you can access you table.

[Use this for restful webservice](http://avilyne.com/?p=105)

using `geocoder` you can find the address corresponding lat and lag

[use this website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.Locale%29)